# Very slow SSH connection unrelated to GSSAPIAuthentication option

Tags: ssh, ssh-keygen

I am having trouble connecting to remote machine through SSH machine (I cannot change SSH configuration on that machine though I can login without any delay from other machines).

I have commented out everything related to `GSSAPIAuthentication` on my local machine SSH config files, both `/etc/ssh/config` and `~/.ssh/config` but id didn't help.

I have also run `ssh` with `-vvv` option and it stops for a while at these lines (marked as `>>>`):

```
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/reachus/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
...
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
>>>debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6
...
debug2: key: /home/reachus/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
>>>debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
```

What can cause this problem. Can my key be broken?

Comment: Can you access the logs on the server?

Comment: Unfortunately no,